# Почему Bash скрипт игнорирует изменение переменной в цикле?

Tags: bash

```
#! /bin/bash
FOLDER="folder"
SOURCE=""
n=0
filter=""

for f in $FOLDER/*.mp4
do
  SOURCE="$SOURCE -i $f"
  filter="$filter [$n] [$n]"
  ((n++))
done
```

Переменная n в цикле не увеличивается и на выходе скрипт выдает:

```
-i folder/1.mp4 -i folder/2.mp4 -i folder/3.mp4 -filter_complex ' [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] ...
```

Где по идее каждая пара скобок должна выглядеть так:  [0] [0] [1] [1] [2] [2]

Comment: [проблема не воспроизводится](https://repl.it/repls/TerrificQualifiedReciprocal)

Comment: @user7860670, хорошо. Тогда вопрос несколько видоизменяется. Что может быть причиной тому, что проблема воспроизводится на vps хостинге (ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS)?

Comment: может у вас там не баш?

Comment: Да, в этом и была проблема

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, так же ли в вашем настоящем коде, но у вас неверный
шебанг:

```sh
#! /bin/bash
```

Должно быть без пробела:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
```

Comment: Всё куда проще и смешнее оказалось, спасибо. В настоящем коде с пробелом

Comment: @АнтонПодгородный  Протестируйте, пожалуйста.  Если мой вариант работает, вы можете отметить его как верный, нажав галочку.

Answer (score 0):

Игнор:

```
sh file.sh
```

Правильный запуск:

```
bash file.sh
```